# How to switch tab by add class and load the templates with JavaScript on a navbar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, cordova

I work on cordova android project, and I want to make a `navbar` with a tab, and when I click on the tab it should load the content with `$("").load('');` and add an `active` class on it.

Adding 'active' class work perfectly

The error is, adding onclick function `switchSimulasi()` is not working

This is my html code :

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top a-navbar box-shadow" id="a-navbar-default" style="z-index:997;">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
               <span class="a-navbar-logo" onclick="openNav()">
                   &#9776; Easly
               </span>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav" id="a-navbar-nav">
                <li class="active active-box-shadow"><a href="#">Beranda</a></li>
                <li onclick="switchSimulasi();"><a href="#">Simulasi Pinjaman</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

and i tried with this javascript code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".nav li").on("click", function() {
        $(".nav li").removeClass("active");
        $(".nav li").removeClass("active-box-shadow");
        $(this).addClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active-box-shadow");
    });

    function switchSimulasi{   
        $("#mainContent").load('template-simulasi-pinjaman.html');
    }
</script>
```

Comment: and what is the error?

Comment: oh i forgot to mention my error, the error is, adding onclick function switchSimulasi() is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Syntax error here: should be

`function switchSimulasi() {
    $("#mainContent").load('template-simulasi-pinjaman.html');
}`

Answer (score 1):

To access `this` value in jQuery using `$(this)`, you should - `$(this)[0]`, so:

```
$(".nav li").on("click", function() {
    $(".nav li").removeClass("active");
    $(".nav li").removeClass("active-box-shadow");
    $(this)[0].addClass("active");
    $(this)[0].addClass("active-box-shadow");
});
```

But in this case, IMO better just plain Js:

```
$(".nav li").on("click", function() {
    $(".nav li").removeClass("active");
    $(".nav li").removeClass("active-box-shadow");
    this.addClass("active");
    this.addClass("active-box-shadow");
});
```

Comment: sorry my error is on adding onclick function switchSimulasi() is not working, i forgot to mention my error on my post